# SFTP Drive cannot get correct volume size of sftp mounted drive

Tags: windows-10, sftp

After installing [SFTP Drive V2](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/) and connecting to my SFTP server ([HiDrive by Strato](https://www.strato.de/cloud-speicher/)) I get the following error messages in the "Service" Tab:

```
[06 07 2021 12:39:58] [TID=013] [INFO] [HiDrive] CBFS Connect OnGetVolumeSize
[06 07 2021 12:39:59] [TID=013] [ERROR] [HiDrive] RemoteFile: /users/USRNAME/*, Error: Statvfs failed [8]: Operation unsupported.
[06 07 2021 12:39:59] [TID=013] [ERROR] [HiDrive] RemoteFile: /users/USRNAME/*, Error: Query avaliable space failed [8]: Operation unsupported.
```

The volume size now appears to be **8 Exabyte** even though it should be 1 Terabyte.

Any idea how to get the correct volume size to show up in File Explorer / File History etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are seeing are non-fatal errors indicating that the server does not support certain extensions such as statvfs or querying available space. The short answer is this server doesn’t allow querying the available space, so SFTP Drive cannot know how much space is available.

SFTP server implementations can vary in the extensions they support. Sometimes you will see these errors in the logs depending on the supported extensions in the server. It is fairly common to see servers which don’t support many extensions.

> Ok, why must the volume size be reported as 8EB?

The volume size will be reported as 8 EB to eliminate the possibility of a bad experience. The application has to choose a very large value to report as the volume size in file explorer. Consider the case where SFTP Drive reports the volume size as *less* than the actual volume size on the remote machine. Then, when a file is written to the drive there is a possibility that Windows will think the disk has run out of space when in reality there may still be space remaining.